# Set an XML attribute and value for multiple selected elements

Tags: inkscape, svg

Within Inkscape I'd like to

1. Select multiple elements, visually
2. Specify an attribute and a value (e.g. "style"="display:none" or "sodipodi:insensitive"="true")
3. End up with all selected elements having the attribute and the value

Perhaps there's an extension that does this? Or some other way?

Answer (score 2):

The short answer to your question is that this is currently not possible with Inkscape. The place where you can edit attributes in the Inkscape interface is the XML editor **Edit > XML Editor** -- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>. Note that if you select an item in the Inkscape drawing, that node will be selected in the XML editor. Also, adding attributes is a little strange too -- simply change the "Name" and "Value" of an exisiting attribute, and click set, and it will be added.

However, the XML editor currently (as of Inkscape 0.91) only supports editing of a single node at a time. There is, however, a (farily old) open feature request to add this on the Inkscape bug tracker: https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape/+bug/170159

Depending on what you are trying to do, you may be able to work around not being able to edit multiple nodes at once, by grouping the items you want, then adding the attribute on the group. (this will work with something like adding a style="display:none", but might not work for other attributes.)